# How to Replace the WordPress Featured Image with a Video?

Tags: posts, theme-development, post-thumbnails, videos, video-player

I need to replace featured images on pages with a video if certain posts contain a video from YouTube, Vimeo, other video hosting services allowed by WordPress.

Here's the pseudo code that I want to use on a custom page:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() {
    if has_video(pseudocode to check whether the single post contains youtube video)  {
// show video player
    } else {
// show post thumbnail
    }
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: This depends on the output of your theme, you can always create a custom field that stores the video link and embed that if found in the output of your theme

Comment: one tip would be to look at your single.php and see where it's displaying the thumbnail.  You'll need to surround that with an if/then statement that says if there is a video (custom field) then show video instead of image.  Without your code or attempts, there is no way to help out more.

Comment: Not sure what is the question here. What is the actual problem you run into while trying to code the solution?

Comment: @MarkKaplun I need to replace the featured image in my WordPress pages with a video player. Or automatically override any existing featured image with a video player if the single post contains an youtube video link. Am I enough clear now? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say for simplicity that you're using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). You need to create a video link field once ACF is installed and assign it to posts. Then, in the post you want a video to show up, add the url. I usually assign this field as a text field and then have users enter the youtube id (last string of text after the `youtube.com` link.

For example, if the video link was: `https://www.youtube.com/J-ek8drxFJA`

the user would enter just `J-ek8drxFJA` in the field.

Now add this code to your single.php copy that is in your child theme folder

Notice that I changed the `if` statement. No need to look for the thumbnail if you're going to use a video:

```
if( get_field( 'video_link' ) ) {
    echo 'this is my video link id ' . get_field( 'video_link' );   // or show video player (see below)
} else {
    if( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) ){
        // show post thumbnail
    }

    //no video or photo
}
```

Now of course if you want to show the video you'll want to do something like this instead:

```
if( get_field( 'video_link' ) ) {
    $videoid = get_field( 'video_link' );
    echo '<h2>Video Link</h2><p>see our video:</p><iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $videoid . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
} else {
    if( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) ) {
        // show post thumbnail
    }
    
    //no video or photo
}
```

Obviously you can change the code up a bit to suit your needs.

Comment: While quality answers of any kind are acceptable do please note that answers referring the user to 3rd party plugins are sometimes not well received. These type of answers have a tendency to generate additional questions regarding forementioned 3rd party plugin and those type of questions are Off Topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give a try to this plugin : 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-video-plus/

If you don't like to use extra plugin then you should definitely look into their code for reference. you can look into their code and customize them as per your requirements.